# Service Fabric: Failed to contact Naming Service, but only from build server

Tags: powershell, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, appveyor

I am using the Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 script to deploy my cluster. From visual studio everything works as expected. From my appveyor build server running the exact same powershell script with the same parameters throws the Failed to contact naming service error. This apparently started out of nowhere. In fact it only fails for my dev enviornment, my qa environment still works on the build server as well. Neither cluster has been touched since it was setup, and no configuration has been changed. Just all of the sudden the error starts happening.

Not including too many details here because this is more of a question about what could cause the exact same deployment script with same parameters to fail in a different environment. Since it works from visual studio I assume it is safe to say the cluster and profiles are setup correctly.

Parameters I am passing into the deployment script are belowser

-ApplicationPackagePath 
-PublishProfileFile 
-DeployOnly:$false 
-UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade $false 
-OverrideUpgradeBehavior 'None'
-OverwriteBehavior 'SameAppTypeAndVersion' 
-SkipPackageValidation:$false 
-ErrorAction Stop

Comment: Sounds like a connection problem between your build server and dev environment. Can you connect to your dev environment at all from your build server?

Comment: According to this https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2558 post, it can be issue with `clusterConnectionParameters` protocol (http versus https) and port. Please add blocking rdp statement (https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/) to connect to build worker and check `clusterConnectionParameters` in publish profile and also try to manually connect to dev environment from build server, as Vaclav suggested.

Comment: @VaclavTurecek What is the best way to test if I can connect? Should I just attempt to load the cluster manager webpage from the build server?

Comment: Eventually figured out that the connection endpoint parameter in my deploy configuration has been deleted by accident for just the dev profile. A developer did it because they didn't realize that if you make changes in the "publish" window in vs it updates the config that is loaded as well.